# jQuery get enter event but don't enter after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been using jQuery to get enter event. As you can see below, when we press enter in the text area, we got the alert but after, the text is entered. I've tried everything but I couldn't find what I could do. Could someone help me?

```js
var jchat = jQuery.noConflict();
jchat("#msg-txt").keypress(function(e){
        var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (keycode == '13'){
            e.stopPropagation();
            if(event.shiftKey){
                if (jchat('#msg-txt').attr('rows') == '1')
                    jchat('#msg-txt').attr('rows', '2');
            } else {
                messageText = jchat('#msg-txt').val();
                alert(messageText)
            }
        }
        
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<textarea id="msg-txt" rows="4" cols="50">
lalalalalaalalala teste lalala
</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do but if you don't want it to enter when you press enter, have you tried using `e.preventDefault()` instead of `stopPropagation()` ?

Comment: I'm beginner using jQuery. I've tried to find something on thew internet but I didn't find. You're right. e.preventDefault() works right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

> e.stopPropagation();

with

> e.preventDefault();

Detailed information will be here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: Thanks ebildin. You're right. I'm beginner using jquery and I didn't find the preventDefault(). I'm sorry for the dumb question, but you helped me!

Answer (score 3):

Use `e.preventDefault();` instead of `e.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing `jchat("#msg-txt").keypress(function(e){` with 
`jchat("#msg-txt").keyup(function(e){`

Answer (score 0):

But my guess is, that you should use `keydown` event instead. Also your next statement is unreachable

```
if(event.shiftKey){
                if (jchat('#msg-txt').attr('rows') == '1')
                    jchat('#msg-txt').attr('rows', '2');
            }
```

Btw, here an example with `keydown` event:

```
var jchat = jQuery.noConflict();
jchat("#msg-txt").on('keydown', function(e){
        var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (keycode == '13'){
            e. preventDefault();
            if(event.shiftKey){
                if (jchat('#msg-txt').attr('rows') == '1')
                    jchat('#msg-txt').attr('rows', '2');
            } else {
                messageText = jchat('#msg-txt').val();
                alert(messageText)
            }
        }

    })
```